# Pagination Question

Tags: php, pagination

How do I change it so that instead of it being 1 2 it is 1 - 2.

Here's the code:

```
$page = $_GET['p'];

for($i = 1; $i <= $totalpages; $i++){ 

if ( $page == $i ) {
echo "<b>$i</b>";
} else {
echo "<a href='?p=$i'>$i</a>-";
}
```

At the moment with the - at the end it comes up as 1-2- but I want it to be 1-2 instead.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
$pagignation = array();
 for($i = 1; $i <= $totalpages; $i++){ 

    if ( $page == $i ) {
       $pagignation[]= "<b>$i</b>";
     } 
    else {
      $pagignation[]= "<a href='?p=$i'>$i</a>";
    }
    }

    echo implode('-',$pagination);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work :

```
$page = $_GET['p'];

for($i = 1; $i <= $totalpages; $i++)
{ 
    if ( $page == $i ) {
        echo "<b>$i</b>";
    } else {
        echo "<a href='?p=$i'>$i</a>";
    }
    if ($i < $totalpages)
        echo '-';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but when I go to http://mywebsite.com/?p=1 it shows up as 1 **2**.. Any ideas?

Comment: Hang on, it does work. It might've just been the page load time?

Comment: Probably something with your browser's cache.